# Coordinates conversion from geographical to spherical

Tags: javascript, jquery, coordinates

I would appreciate if anyone could help me with a conersion of coordinates.
Basically, I have downloaded and integrated the following plug-in into my website:

http://sebastien.drouyer.com/jquery.earth-3d/

It is basically a script that creates a model of a globe. Now what I want to do is to display a particular point on the globe, just like in the demo, which you can see on the page. 
The problem is, that in the code, the coordinates of the points are given as for example in the demo:

```
alpha: 1 * Math.PI / 4,
delta: -2 * Math.PI / 4,
```

Now what I would like to do is to display a particular point, location on Earth, given I have the normal geographical coordinates, i.e. latitude and longitude.

I was trying to search on the internet and found some formulae, but neither of them worked and basically after pluging them in the point just randomly jumped all over the globe.

In the domcumentation of the script it just says "Render locations by indicating spherical coordinates". I looke up spherical coordinates on wikipedia, but that didnt really help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the same points and just add the radius of the earth :http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/conversion-between-spherical-and-cartesian-coordinates-systems/.